# Learning to implement a C++ BubbleSort using function pointers

Tags: c++, function, sorting, pointers

My compare function is a simple return true or false. My BubbleSort works by going through the vector once, sorting it once, but not going back to continue to sort. So if the numbers are 1, 5, 2, 4, 3, 6, I will get 5, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3. Instead of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. If I use my bool swapped, there is an error. Here is the code:

```
void bSort(vector<int> &vector1, bool (*compare) (int a, int b))
{
    bool swapped = true; //using swapped in following code causes crash
    while(swapped)
    {
        swapped = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < vector1.size(); ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < vector1.size(); ++j)
                {
                    if ((*compare)(vector1[i], vector1[j]) == true)
                    {
                        swap(vector1[i], vector1[j]);
                        swapped = true;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

I have seen a function like this before, and now I am trying to implement it because I want to learn. Please help.

EDIT:
Here is the fixed and working function! :)

```
void bSort(vector<int> &vector1, bool (*compare) (int a, int b))
    {
        bool swapped = true;
        while(swapped)
        {
            swapped = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < vector1.size(); ++i)
                {
                        if ((*compare)(vector1[i], vector1[i+1]) == true)
                        {
                            swap(vector1[i], vector1[i+1]);
                            swapped = true;
                        }
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hint: what happens if `i` > `j`?

Comment: Q: Where does `iv` even come from? It isn't a parameter, and isn't a local. And you don't need to nest two loops in your `while` wrapper. you only need one and a descending length limit controlled by the outer-most while loop. (i.e. `vector1.size()` should only appear once in this code, and *not* in a loop).

Comment: Your working function is still not bubblesort, and still has a bug. The *top* end of the  for-loop should not be `vector1.size()`. Doing that has you repeatedly sorting already-sorted data. [See how to fix that here](http://pastebin.com/MeR02G1A). The bug mentioned happens when `i == vector1.size()-1` (the last iteration of the i-loop). In that case `vector1[i+1]` is out of range and invokes undefined behavior. That bug is also addressed in the linked paste, btw.

Comment: Aside: function pointers are sort of odd, in that you can just write  `compare(x,y)` rather than `(*compare)(x,y)`. Also, normally in C++ one writes a template and you can pass in any callable with the right arguments, rather than being limited specifically to function pointers.